# Deploying rails app Capistrano plenty ERRORS

Tags: windows, git, ruby-on-rails-3.1, github, capistrano

i am trying to deploy my rails application for the first time on vexxhost. i am using github as my Source code management and capistrano.

here is my deploy file

```
   require 'bundler/capistrano'
   require 'capistrano'
   require 'bundler'
   require 'capistrano-vexxhost'

   # Account Settings

   ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true
   set :scm_command, "/home/user/opt/bin/git"
   set :local_scm_command,"git"
   set :user, "xxxxxxxx"
   set :password, "xxxxxxxxx"
   set :domain, "domain.com"
   set :mount_path,"/home/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx"
   set :application,"app name"
   set :scm, :git
   set :deploy_via, :copy
   set :repository, "git@github.com:xxxxx/xxxxxxx.git"
   default_run_options[:pty] = true
```

PROBLEM NO 1)

As soon as i installed gem 'capistrano' gem 'capistrano-vexxhost' i got the following error when trying to run my application locally (it was working before installing capistrano).

```
 C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.14.1/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:18:in `instance': Please require this file from within a Capistrano recipe (LoadError)
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-vexxhost-1.0.3/lib/capistrano-vexxhost/capistrano_integration.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-vexxhost-1.0.3/lib/capistrano-vexxhost.rb:2:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-vexxhost-1.0.3/lib/capistrano-vexxhost.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler.rb:128:in `require'
    from C:/Users/mummy/LagoAds/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in     `require'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

**NOTE** But as i soon as i comment the **Bundler.require** line from the following code in  the application.rb file, it successfully runs but doesn't recognize the gems

```
  if defined?(Bundler)
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
  Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
  end
```

PROBLEM NO 2) 
when is type "cap deploy:check" on my ruby command prompt i the get the following error. 
[image]

PROBLEM NO 3)
when is type "cap deploy:cold" on my ruby command prompt i get the following error

[image]

Is there anything missing from my deploy.rb or is there anything i didnt do.

**PLEASE I NEED HELP, I HAVE BEEN ON THIS PROBLEM FOR VERY LONG TIME. I AM NEW TO DEPLOYING WEB APPLICATIONS AND RAILS HAVE BEEN VERY DIFFICULT FOR ME**

PLEASE HELP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problems 2 & 3**
Your second and third problems are the result of git and tar not being in your path. Either they are not installed at all, or your path is incomplete. See the errors I quoted below.

**problem 2**

```
 'git' could not be found on the local host
 'tar' could not be found on the local host
```

**problem 3**

```
 no such file or directory git ls-remote...
```

**Problem 1**

Unfortunately I have no answer for #1. A guess would be that you need to add `capistrano` and/or `capistrano-vexxhost` to your `deploy.rb`.